# How to find max consecutive numbers of one value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this, there are two columns, id and item. 
I want to find the max consecutive occurrence for one item.

[image: original table]

And I want to return the result like below:

[image: return value]

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Can't really tell what you are asking by this. Please include as well the code for what you have tried, so we can modify it and help you the best we can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps and islands problem and rather tricky.  To get the islands you can subtract an increasing number from the `id`:

```
select item, min(id), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by item, (id - seqnum);
```

To get the maximum, add a `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (item) item, min(id), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by item, id - seqnum
order by item, count(*) desc;
```